# Where can I find an old work ceiling box for armored cable?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I've got a single ceiling box/light fixture in my dining room which is wired up with BX. I'd like to have a second box about five feet from it. I'd run a new piece of BX nutted between the two boxes and then nut the wires to each fixture accordingly. The run is parallel to the joists so don't need to drill through those.

Thing is, I can't seem to find an "old work" ceiling box for BX. Why would they have nice deep ones for NM cable, but not for BX? Lowes has these ["shallow" boxes](https://www.lowes.com/pd/RACO-1-Gang-Gray-Steel-Old-Work-Shallow-Round-Ceiling-Electrical-Box/1000876432), but not quite sure how they work. Maybe they are designed to hang another box off of them? No way you'd get a wire nut in there.

Comment: Metal old work boxes are commonly available in normal times. These are not normal times, what with global supply chain breakdown. You may just need to keep searching for one in stock, or contact a local supply house for a favor.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. So, they do exist, if you can find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes your local big house stores don't carry the stuff you need and you need to go to an electrical supply store.

That being said, there are boxes like the one shown below that are old work and will handle BX.
[image]

There are also old work metal boxes that just have the knockouts. In that case you would need a few of the connectors shown below that are designed for BX.

[image]

This stuff is out there, just keep looking.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the info on the connectors as well.